# Nested for loop to match vowels by iterating over strings and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to loop over a list, and match each character in that list with characters in a string:

```
wordlist = ['big', 'cats', 'like', 'really']
vowels = "aeiou"
count = 0
 for i in range(len(wordlist)):
    for j in vowels:
        if j in wordlist[i]:
            count +=1
            print(j,'occurs', count,'times')
```

to return `"a" occurs 2 times.` for each vowel but this does not work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I can see a single space before the first `for` declaration. Maybe this is affecting your Python's Code Indentation.

Comment: What exactly is your overall goal? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? apologies if this is too simple of a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
wordlist = ['big', 'cats', 'like', 'really']
vowels = "aeiou"        
for v in vowels:
    count = 0
    for word in wordlist:
        if v in word:
            count += 1
    print(v,'occurs', count, 'times')
```

results:

```
a occurs 2 times
e occurs 2 times
i occurs 2 times
o occurs 0 times
u occurs 0 times
```

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: Cheers juanpa, wasnt me who downvoted you.

Answer (score 2):

Using a collections.Counter here is probably the most pythonic way and also avoids nested for loops

```
import collections
vowels = "aeiou"
wordlist = ['big', 'cats', 'like', 'really']

letters = collections.Counter("".join(wordlist))
for letter in vowels:
    print(letter, "occurs", letters.get(letter, 0), "times")
```

This outputs:

```
a occurs 2 times
e occurs 2 times
i occurs 2 times
o occurs 0 times
u occurs 0 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version:

```
wordlist = ['big', 'cats', 'like', 'really']
vowels = "aeiou"
for j in vowels:
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(wordlist)):
        if j in wordlist[i]:
            count += 1
    print(j, 'occurs', count, 'times')
```

Note that `j` is a terrible name, it should really be `vowel`.

Comment: Thank you Alex! I will change `j` to `vowel` as you suggest.

Comment: You don't need an index at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the point was to teach by only showing the necessary changes.